# Removing header in aomart class

Tags: header-footer

I'm writing a paper using the `aomart` package/class. Since this package was written specifically for papers submitted to the Annals of Mathematics, it has an automatic header.

Since I don't actually plan on submitting this paper to the Annals, I would like to remove this header, since it's useless in my case.

This is a MWE which produces the "problem":

```
\documentclass[final]{aomart}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\title{test}

\begin{document}
    \maketitle
\end{document}
```

[image]

I would like to get rid of this header entirely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking through the `aomart.cls` file, I found which lines to add to the preamble. This preamble should look like

```
\documentclass[final]{aomart}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\makeatletter % https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/8351/134574
\fancypagestyle{firstpage}{%
  \fancyhf{}%
  \if@aom@manuscript@mode
    \lhead{\begin{picture}(0,0)%
        \put(-21,-25){\usebox{\@aom@linecount}}%
      \end{picture}}
  \fi
  \chead{}%
   \cfoot{\footnotesize\thepage}}%
\doinumber{}
\makeatother

\title{test}

\begin{document}
    \maketitle
\end{document}
```

Comment: The 13th line says `Any modified versions of this file must be renamed with new filenames distinct from aomart.cls`. Per the LPPL license you can't modify a file without changing its name. Please, instead show only the modified parts as redefinitions or patches and then remove the class file from your answer.

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik Good call, I just did.

Comment: Thanks :-) If you allow me to nitpick on your answer, I'd suggest you to copy the entire `\fancypagestyle{firstpage}{...}` to your document and change the `\chead` in there instead of directly changing the class file (which shouldn't be done, ever), [like this](https://pastebin.com/raw/HcjJ1fVQ). This is a better approach because: 1. Your answer will be easier for a novice to just copy/paste instead of trying to figure out how to change the class file and 2. It won't depend on line numbers (my version doesn't match those numbers, for example).